# How to format a CSV with blank data in some places

Tags: microsoft-excel, formatting, csv

I have a CSV with the following headings (and example data):

```
Serial Number, Photocopier Model, Copy Volume, MeterType
432322,Canon,Copy Volume, MeterType
,,23423,BW
,,983,Colour
,,4405,A3 BW
,,34,A3 Colour
```

This CSV might have 1000 of these in it, based on the serial number of the device. Some have `A3` and some don’t so I cant just duplicate the “Serial Number” down those 4 example rows.

Does anyone have any idea of how I can extract the “Copy Volume” values for each serial no?

Answer (score 1):

So, I think I can do it this way [as explained on this site](https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/184232-vlookup-retrieves-data-different-row.html). `=INDEX(B2:B15,MATCH(C15,A2:A15,0)-1)` Is the solution this is looking a value in `C15` and finding a match in `A2:A15` and then giving a match value in `B2:B15` minus one row for it. You can use this also for finding a value to the left of your original column.

Comment: =INDEX(B2:B15,MATCH(C15,A2:A15,0)-1) Is the solution

this is looking a value in C15 and finding a match in A2:A15 and then giving a match value in B2:B15 minus one row for it.

You can use this also for finding a value to the left of your original column.

Comment: I would still prefer a better solution if you know if one. This doesn't solve the problem completely.